# Programmatically adding dynamically named checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am programmatically trying to add a checkbox with a unique ID to a div:

```
        foreach (var item in tweetList)
        {
            Panel tweetPanel = new Panel();
            tweetPanel.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            tweetPanel.BorderWidth = 1;
            tweetPanel.Attributes["style"] = "padding: 20px; margin 20px; width: 20%;"; 
            tweets.Controls.Add(tweetPanel);
            CheckBox tweetChecker = new CheckBox();
            tweetChecker.ID = "checkBox" + count;
            tweetPanel.Controls.Add(tweetChecker);
            tweetPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<img src=\"" + item.profileImageUrl + "\">"));
            count++;
        }
```

in this div:

```
    <div id="tweets" runat="server">
    </div>
```

But when I run it it says:

Control 'checkBox0' of type 'CheckBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Why wouldn't a programmatically created check box not be considered server side? And how do I fix this

Comment: wrap div with a form runat server, asp.net needs all server side controls in a form

Comment: The check box *is* considered server-side.  But you're not placing it inside a server-side form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controls need to be inside a form element so that they can be posted to the server when the form is submitted.

```
<form id="myForm" runat="server">
    <!-- your controls -->
    <div id="tweets" runat="server">
    </div>
</form>
```

You can only add controls outside of a form element if those controls do not cause a postback.